# Removing windows 7 from the E drive without impacting other OS

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, uninstall

I had Windows XP installed in my system (D:/) after that I had installed Windows 7 on E:.

How can I unstall Windows 7 from E:\ safely and without impacting Windows XP on D:\ ?

**Edit** Am I on the wrong forum or my question doesn't have any sense ? I am not getting sufficient information about uninstalling it and I don't know where should I ask this question.

Comment: I ain't sure how can I do it now. I have no other place to ask this question. May be I have to live with it :(

Comment: Did you read our [faq]? This is a site for professional sysadmins managing systems in a professional capacity.

Comment: @MdMarra Do I need to post this on #SuperUser ?

Comment: Possibly, but read their faq first and search for similar  questions before asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple logon to windows from other drive (D:), then format the E: Drive. After formatting it, remove the boot entry for other windows from c:\boot.ini file. thats all